# Passport.js req.user undefined or empty string if I Fetch (or send request) from the Frontend (React) but Fetching via Postman Works

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, passport.js

I've already read all the req.user undefined Post on SO, but after 3 days I have yet to find a solution, so please don't be mad for yet another req.user undefined question.

I've setup a normal Passport.js Local User Authentication. EVERYTHING works from Registration, to Login and to Logout perfectly,except when I try to fetch the User / User Session from the frontend. BUT fetching (or requestion) the user / user session through Postman works just fine, I get everything displayed perfectly and even the server console.logs me the user info instead of undefined, unlike when I try to fetch it from the Frontend.

I've modified my Cors & Fetch Code countless time in the last 3 days and I'm truly at my wits end.

<-- Backend (Node/Express) Code -->

```
// App
    const app: Application = express();

    app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
    app.use(express.json());

    app.use(cors({ origin: 'http://localhost:3000', credentials: true }));
    // I've even tried to include methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE" with NO success.
    // I've tried with and without origin or credentials.

// Express Session
    app.use(session({
        // secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET
        secret: 'whatever the secret is',
        resave: false,
        store: new pgSessionStore({
            pool: pool,
            tableName: 'session'
        }),
        saveUninitialized: true,
        cookie: {  maxAge: 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 } //One year
    }))
    // Initialize passport & session
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());
    // Auth
    initializePassport(passport);

    // Routes
    app.use(mountRoutes);
```

<-- Frontend (React.js) Code -->
I've tried Axios & Fetch in different 'Config' Variants that Fetch, Axios & Cors could offer.

```
 const requestUser = () => {
        fetch("http://localhost:3001/users", {
            method: "GET",
            mode: 'cors',
            credentials: 'include',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                
            },


        }).then((res) => console.log(res)).catch(err => console.log(err))


    const config = {
        withCredentials: true,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
    };
    const url = 'http://localhost:3001/users'
    const getUser = () => {
        axios.get(url, config).then((res) => {
            console.log(res.data);});
    }
```

I'm truly at my wits and and I hope someone could help me. Maybe Iam just unable to see the forest infront of the tree after 3 days. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The session is not passed across origin.

Comment: Hey Thank you for your answer. Would you mind if you could eloborate on that?